# Retrieve value from Array of Hashes Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes in ruby like this

```
blah = [{"key1"=>"value1","key2"=>"value2","key3"=>"value3"....}]
```

Now let's say I want to get the value of key2.

What I am doing is `puts "key 2 is #{blah["key2"]}"`, but then I get `ERROR: "no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`blah` is an array so you could have more than one hash inside it with a `"key2"` key. let's find them all

```
p blah.map { |h| h['key2'] }
```

or if you know there is just one hash in your array

```
p blah[0]['key2']
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to the [answer from Ursus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74304415/15261315), if you wish to find the *first* value associated with `"key2"` in any hash in your array, you could use `#find` with a block.

Consider:

```
foo = [ {a: 5, b: 6}, 
        {f: 67, key2: 42}, 
        {d: 27.3}, 
        {key2: 35} ]

h = foo.find { |h| h.has_key? :key2 }
# => {f: 67, key2: 42}

puts h[:key2] unless h.nil?
```